# Vary different parameters each time I call a function in Python

Tags: python, input, keyword-argument

I have a function

```
def input_definition(parameter_variation=None):

    input_def = {}
    input_def['a'] = 1
    input_def['b'] = 2
    input_def['c'] = 3
    ...
    input_def['z'] = 26

    # Apply the parameter variation by means of the input argument 'parameter_variation'.
    # ...

    # Save 'input_def' to external file with dill module.
    # ...
```

with many parameters. I want to vary some of these parameters by giving `parameter_variation` to the function `input_definition`. I need to vary different parameters each time I call `input_definition`.

So one time `parameter_variation` contains values for `a` and `b` and another time `parameter_variation` contains values for `c` and `d`.

What is the best / most neat / Pythonic way to do this? Or is it perhaps better to use kwargs?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `kwargs` for this like so:

```
def some_func(**kwargs):
    my_dict = dict(
        a=1,
        b=2,
        c=3,
        d=4
    )
    my_dict.update(**kwargs)
```

This will set your defaults and then override them with kwargs.

It is arguable better to give more limited inputs to the dict by simply using default arguments like so:

```
def some_func(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
    my_dict = dict(
        a=a,
        b=b,
        c=c,
        d=d
    )
```

This is more secure and makes your intentions more understandable to someone reading your code. But is less flexible in comparison to `kwargs`.

Comment: @Adriaan if this answered your question please mark it as the correct answer to help future people looking for the same issue :-).